How to validate multi-tenant issuer-value in Keycloak with Azure Entra ID being the IDP
We're in a process of introducing Entra ID (multi-tenant) to our Keycloak SSO instance. We've configured it using Keyclok's Open ID Connect identity provider setup.
As one can see from the screenshot, we've configured it using Microsoft's recommendation.
Keycloak IDP entra ID openid connect config
There is still one problem: We believe that the issuer field shouldn't be empty from security perspective but cannot figure out how to make this work on Keycloak.
It's possible to find the issuer key from Microsoft's provided public keys:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/discovery/v2.0/keys
..which contains the value:
"issuer":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/v2.0"

(it's also in their documentation).
In short, everything works correctly when we keep the issuer-field empty, but from security standpoint, it should most likely be filled?
Seems like it isn't possibly to put template-values to Issuer-field, we've tried for example:
- https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/v2.0
- https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantid}/v2.0
- https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/v2.0

But everytime it fails with the message of:
Wrong issuer from token. Got: https://login.microsoftonline.com/<customer-tenant-id>/v2.0 expected: <our issuer uri we provided in keycloak's configuration>

Have anyone else tried something similar? Any suggestions on how to continue troubleshooting this? How can we send the issuer-verification to correct issuer URI dynamically?
For clarification, there will be an unknown amount of Entra ID tenants present in our SSO.

Add the issuer to the IDP configuration in a comma-separated manner. And the validation will pass through.
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<customer-tenant-id-1>/v2.0, https://login.microsoftonline.com/<customer-tenant-id-2>/v2.0

